# How to avoid the google Sign In Pop up when the user is already logged in?

Tags: javascript, oauth, google-api, google-signin, google-plus-signin

I am using the below code to make a user sign in through google.

```
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api:client.js"></script>
  <script>
      var googleUser = {};
      var startApp = function () {
          gapi.load('auth2', function () {
              // Retrieve the singleton for the GoogleAuth library and set up the client.
              auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
                  client_id: [my client id],
                  cookiepolicy: 'single_host_origin',
                  // Request scopes in addition to 'profile' and 'email'
                  scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me'
              });
          });
      };

      function checkUser() {
          if (auth2.isSignedIn.get()) {
              onSignIn(auth2.currentUser.po.po);
          }
          else {
              gapi.auth.authorize({ client_id: [my client id], scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me', immediate: false }, onSignIn);
          }
      }

      function onSignIn(googleUser) {
          alert('Access Token' + googleUser.access_token);
          //location.href = "ServerSide.aspx?acccessToken=" + googleUser.access_token;
      }
  </script>
  <style type="text/css">
    #customBtn {
      display: inline-block;
      background: #4285f4;
      color: white;
      width: 190px;
      border-radius: 5px;
      white-space: nowrap;
    }
    #customBtn:hover {
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    span.label {
      font-weight: bold;
    }
    span.icon {
      /*background: url('/identity/sign-in/g-normal.png') transparent 5px 50% no-repeat;*/
      display: inline-block;
      vertical-align: middle;
      width: 42px;
      height: 42px;
      border-right: #2265d4 1px solid;
    }
    span.buttonText {
      display: inline-block;
      vertical-align: middle;
      padding-left: 42px;
      padding-right: 42px;
      font-size: 14px;
      font-weight: bold;
      /* Use the Roboto font that is loaded in the <head> */
      font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    }
  </style>
  <!-- In the callback, you would hide the gSignInWrapper element on a
  successful sign in -->
  <div id="gSignInWrapper" onclick="checkUser()">
    <span class="label">Sign in with:</span>
    <div id="customBtn" class="customGPlusSignIn">
      <span class="icon"></span>`enter code here`
      <span class="buttonText">Google</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="name"></div>
  <script>startApp();</script>
```

With this code if the user is even logged in to google the pop comes and go which looks weird.So i want if the user is logged in to google popup should not come and directly makes the user enter the system.
For this i have used "auth2.isSignedIn.get()" on button click but this function always gives me false even if the user is logged in to the google.
I am stuck at this point.Please if you have any way to achieve this do tell me.

Comment: OAuth relies on the authentication being offloaded onto the authenticating web site (in this case google). It's security feature, your web site never sees the user credentials, only google see's them. So you always need to open a window to the authenticating web site, even if that web site just says, yes this user is logged in.

Comment: I think you need to add approval_prompt=force

Comment: @Liam...I am able to achieve this thing in Facebook and LinkedIn and i am using OAuth there but i wonder its not working for Google....

Comment: @DaImTo...i think approval_prompt is to avoid the initial scope permission popup however i want login popup which comes and go should not appear if the user is already logged in.. correct me if i am wrong and if there is any other way to achieve this..

Answer (score 0):

isSignedIn method is available on google auth instance [GoogleAuth.isSignedIn.get()](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference#googleauthissignedinget), you should use below

> gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.get()